# \endgroup error when using \makebox and gather

Tags: math-mode

I'm getting this error when I try to use \makebox to center several equations that run longer than the textwidth. If I use `$$ .. $$`, I don't seem to have the issue. Why?

Code that throws ! Missing \endgroup inserted ... :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\begin{gather*}
\text{Some long equation.}
\end{gather*}
}
\end{document}
```

Code that does work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
$$ \text{Some long equation.} $$
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\makebox` is like `\mbox` and is a horizontal box that can not contain display material. The code that "does work" is just redundant `$$` does not start display math it is like `$ $` and is just an empty inline math

Comment: But it does work in the sense that if you input a large equation that is larger than the textwidth, using \makebox around $ .. $ or $$ .. $$ will make it centered while not using \makebox will make it go off the right side. I have a large set of equations though so I was hoping something like gather would work.

Comment: No the bit between `$$` and `$$` is not in math mode, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Your solution works, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean about it not working with the '$ $' style. If I make a one dimensional table of equations inside '$ $', I get that with the \makebox, it properly centers them.

Comment: your example above has `{$$ ..... $$}` normally the `.....` would be in display math, but not here that is a text `.....` surrounded by an empty inline math to the left and another to the right. It is because `$$` does not start display math that you get an error from `gather`

Comment: Okay, well my point is that it worked for me when I replace \text{some long equation} with some long equation like 60 X's in a row (without using \text{} in any capacity).

Comment: But it's not in math mode, so you could omit the `$` and the `\text` and it would do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not have display constructs in a horizontal box. If you need to change the margins locally you need an environment like `quote` :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{outdent}
               {\list{}{\leftmargin-2cm
                \rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{gather}
aaaaa = bbbb\\
aaaa=b+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c
\end{gather}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{outdent}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{gather}
aaaaa = bbbb\\
aaaa=b+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c+c
\end{gather}
\end{outdent}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution with `\mathclap` from `mathtools`. Example (I used the `showframe` option of `geometry` to help visualise centring):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
   \mathclap{E(h)-E(h+1) =(kz*r+kz)\sin \frac{Gz}{r+1}+(-r^2-2*r-1)\cos \frac{Gz}{r+1}+\Bigl(kz\sin \frac{Gz}{r}+ky*\sin \frac{Gy}{r}+kx\sin \frac{Gz}{r}+6\Bigr)*r}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]